# Get opposite of collection date times within the same day

Tags: c#, .net-core, intervals

I am wondering if anyone can help me, I have a collection of work start times and end times within a single day. I want to show the opposite also, so the times to which the person has not worked on that day. The issue I am having with my code is that it is carrying onto the next day whereas I just want that day.

```
public class WorkDay
{
    public DateTime Day { get; set; }
    public List<Worked> WorkingTimes { get; set; }
}

public class Worked
{
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
}


static class Program
{

    static void Main()
    {

    var now = DateTime.Now;
    var year = now.Year;
    var month = now.Month;
    var day = now.Day;

    var Day = new WorkDay
    {
        Day = now,
        WorkingTimes = new List<Worked>
        {
            new Worked { Start = new DateTime(year,month, day,8,30,0), End = new DateTime(year,month, day,10,30,0) },
            new Worked { Start = new DateTime(year,month, day,10,45,0), End = new DateTime(year,month, day,14,30,0)  },
            new Worked { Start = new DateTime(year,month, day,14,50,0), End = new DateTime(year,month, day,14,50,0).AddHours(10) }
        }
    };

        foreach (var time in Day.WorkingTimes)
            Console.WriteLine($"Start {time.Start} " + $"End {time.End}");

        Day.WorkingTimes = Day.WorkingTimes.OrderBy(x => x.Start).ToList();

        var opposite = Opposite(Day);

        foreach (var time in opposite)
            Console.WriteLine($"Start {time.Start} " + $"End {time.End}");

        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Worked> Opposite(WorkDay workDay)
    {
        var rested = new List<Worked>();

        for (var i = workDay.WorkingTimes.Count(); i-- > 0;)
            if (i - 1 != -1 && workDay.WorkingTimes[i - 1].End != workDay.WorkingTimes[i].Start)
                rested.Add(new Worked { Start = workDay.WorkingTimes[i - 1].End, End = workDay.WorkingTimes[i].Start });

        rested = rested.OrderBy(x => x.Start).ToList();

        var lastEntry = rested.Last().End.Date;
        var lastTime = new DateTime(lastEntry.Year, lastEntry.Month, lastEntry.Day, 23, 59, 59, 59);

        if (lastTime > rested.Last().End)
            rested.Add(new Worked
            { Start = workDay.WorkingTimes.Last().End, End = lastTime });

        return rested;
    }

}
```

So the output would be:
Worked:

```
Start 21/09/2020 08:30:00 End 21/09/2020 10:30:00
Start 21/09/2020 10:45:00 End 21/09/2020 14:30:00
Start 21/09/2020 14:50:00 End 22/09/2020 00:50:00
```

Opposite:

```
Start 21/09/2020 10:30:00 End 21/09/2020 10:45:00
Start 21/09/2020 14:30:00 End 21/09/2020 14:50:00
Start **22/09/2020** 00:50:00 End 21/09/2020 23:59:59
```

What I am trying to do is not go into the next day calculating the difference. So in the WorkDay class there is the Day and all dates must be from that day.

So that the 24 hours of that day is accounted for (either worked or not), so if they did not work it should be accounted for within the result of the Opposite method.

Comment: The Date property of a DateTime truncated the date to midnight at the start of the day.  So you can use : WorkingTimes.GroupBy(x => x.Date).ToList();

Comment: Suggestion for better/quicker answer. Make your example have concrete start/end times and show what your expected result would be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would tackle this by modelling a period of time and then provide a method that could `Cut` out a section of time from that period. Then it becomes trivial to work out the remainder of the day.

Let's start with the `Period` class:

```
private sealed class Period : IEquatable<Period>
{
    public DateTime StartTime { get; private set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; private set; }

    public Period(DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime)
    {
        this.StartTime = startTime;
        this.EndTime = endTime;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is Period)
            return Equals((Period)obj);
        return false;
    }

    public bool Equals(Period obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (!EqualityComparer<DateTime>.Default.Equals(this.StartTime, obj.StartTime))
            return false;
        if (!EqualityComparer<DateTime>.Default.Equals(this.EndTime, obj.EndTime))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hash = 0;
        hash ^= EqualityComparer<DateTime>.Default.GetHashCode(this.StartTime);
        hash ^= EqualityComparer<DateTime>.Default.GetHashCode(this.EndTime);
        return hash;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{{ StartTime = {0}, EndTime = {1} }}",
            this.StartTime, this.EndTime);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Period> Cut(Period that)
    {
        if (that.StartTime <= this.StartTime)
        {
            if (that.EndTime <= this.StartTime)
            {
                yield return this;
            }
            else if (that.EndTime < this.EndTime)
            {
                yield return new Period(that.EndTime, this.EndTime);
            }
        }
        else if (that.StartTime < this.EndTime)
        {
            if (that.EndTime < this.EndTime)
            {
                yield return new Period(this.StartTime, that.StartTime);
                yield return new Period(that.EndTime, this.EndTime);
            }
            else
            {
                yield return new Period(this.StartTime, that.StartTime);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            yield return this;
        }
    }
}
```

Now we can express the current working times like this:

```
var workingTimes = new[]
{
    new Period(new DateTime(year, month, day, 8, 30, 0), new DateTime(year, month, day, 10, 30, 0)),
    new Period(new DateTime(year, month, day, 10, 45, 0), new DateTime(year, month, day, 14, 30, 0)),
    new Period(new DateTime(year, month, day, 14, 50, 0), new DateTime(year, month, day, 14, 50, 0).AddHours(10)),
};
```

Then the whole day is:

```
var whole = new Period(now.Date, now.Date.AddDays(1.0));
```

Now we can compute the remainder of the day simply like this:

```
var result = new [] { whole };
foreach (var d in workingTimes)
{
    result = result.SelectMany(r => r.Cut(d)).ToArray();
}
```

My end result is:

```
2020/09/21 00:00 - 2020/09/21 08:30 
2020/09/21 10:30 - 2020/09/21 10:45 
2020/09/21 14:30 - 2020/09/21 14:50
```

Comment: Thank you. A nice elegant and easy to follow solution to the problem, I made a small change to stop going to the next day. Thanks for your help.                     if (StartTime.Day == EndTime.Day)  yield return new Period(that.EndTime, this.EndTime); else   yield return new Period(that.EndTime, this.EndTime.AddTicks(-1));

Comment: @JimboJones - No worries. If I were you I would implement a `Fragment` method that works like `Cut` but also returns the `that` `Period` (fragmenting that if it overlaps with the  `this`). Then you can call `Fragment` passing in the full current day and simply filter out any fragments that don't start on the same day.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution might be to filter the `rested` result by only those values where the `Start` and `End` match the `Day`

```
// last line of method "Opposite"
return rested.Where(o => o.Start.Date == workDay.Day.Date && o.End.Date == workDay.Day.Date);
```

Comment: If this is not what you were after, please update your question with some concrete examples including expected result and I'll happily update this answer.